# Is there a complete list of Seussian transportation?

Tags: dr-seuss

From Zike-bike in Marvin K Mooney to the weird car with a goat in Green Eggs and Ham, Dr Seuss had an insane amount of imaginary vehicles.

Is there a complete list of Seussian transportation?

Comment: http://seuss.wikia.com/wiki/Marvin_K._Mooney

Comment: @Valorum thanks! That covers one book!

Comment: Philip Nel has written several academic books on Dr. Seuss. You might see if he has done such a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find an actual list of Seussian vehicles, but never fear!

[Who's Who and What's What in the Books of Dr. Seuss is here!](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~library/digital/collections/books/ocm45408191/ocm45408191.html)

This resource is easily ALT-F searchable and reveals wubbleloads of information about all the cars, waggons, trolleys, bikes and other assorted vehicles and the beasts that pull, drag and draw them. Each heading is broken down into relevant book citations.

Comment: I love that you rhymed your answer! :)